# Classic ASP: CSS doesn't apply to content place holder in master page

Tags: css, asp-classic

Revamping the existing website(constructed using frames) using master pages in classic asp web application.
I have created three 3 separate pages(header,content,footer) and bind the other pages and it works fine.
In few scenerioes I have to call/display a page within a page in that case the whole page loads.(header and footer)

```
Header Page

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     
    <title>ABC Company</title>
    <!-- basic -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!-- bootstrap css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <!-- site css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
 <body id="default_theme" class="home_page1">

ContentHolder Page
    <!--#include file="Header.asp"--> 
     <div id="content">
          <% Call ContentHolder() %>
     </div>
    <!--#include file="Footer.asp"-->
    
PartsPage 
    <!--#include file="Content.asp"-->
    <% Sub ContentHolder() %>
       <object data="mylogin.asp" width="100%" height="700" type="text/html">
           Content
       </object>
    <% End Sub %>

mylogin.asp Page

<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<% Option Explicit

    Session("LoginID")="validuser"
    Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
    Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
    Sssion("user_id")=""
    Session("user_type")=""
%>
<!--#include file="Content.asp"-->

<% Sub ContentPlaceHolder() %> 

<div id="Layer3">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <p>
                Please enter your UserID and Password<BR>
             </p>
             <FORM name="MyForm" method="post" action="myLogin1.asp">
                <p>
                   UserID<BR>
                   <INPUT type="text" name="LoginID" id="LoginID" tabindex="1"><BR><BR>
                   Password<BR>
                   <INPUT type="password" name="PWD" id="PWD" tabindex="2"><BR><BR>               
                   <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit Login Information" name="submit1" tabindex="3">
                </p>
             </FORM>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<% End Sub %>

Footer Page
      <footer>
         <div class=row>
            <p>
              <span>All right reserved. &copy;2020 ABC Pvt Ltd. </span>
            </p>
         </div>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

So I removed server side include from the ContentHolder Page which resolves the above issue but CSS doesn't apply to ContentHolder Page.

```
ContentHolder Page
 
     <div id="content">
          <% Call ContentHolder() %>
     </div>
     
    
ContactUsPage 
    <!--#include file="Content.asp"-->
    <% Sub ContentHolder() %>
       <h5> Contact Us</h5>
       <p> If you have a question or a comment </p>  
    <% End Sub %>
```

[image]

I'm not well versed in Classic ASP, so any help you could provide would be helpful.

HTML Source

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>   
    <title>ABC Company</title>
    <!-- basic -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!-- bootstrap css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <!-- site css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
      <!-- responsive css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" />
      <!-- colors css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors.css" />
      <!-- wow animation css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" />     
</head>
 <body id="default_theme" class="home_page1">
           <!-- header -->
      <header class="header header_style1">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                  <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="#" /></a></div>
                  <div class="main_menu float-right">
                      <div class="menu">
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li class="active"><a href="master.asp">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Our Services.html">About</a></li>                                  
                                   <li><a href="myparts2.asp?op=labour">Labour</a></li>                                   
                                  <li><a href="myparts2.asp?op=parts"> Parts</a></li>                                               
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                  <div class="right_bt"><a class="bt_main" href="accounttype.asp">Login</a> </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </header>
      <div id="content">
            <object data="mylogin.asp" width="100%" height="700" type="text/html">
      
            </object>
      </div>
   <!-- footer -->
       <footer>    
       </footer>
      <!-- end footer -->
 </body>
```

Comment: There is no such concept in Classic ASP of "master pages" that is ASP.Net speak. What you have here are a series of SSI (Server Side Include) files that get stitched into the preprocessed ASP page before the server returns the HTML. How you use them to build up a page is entirely up to you and there is no magic function that makes it all work.

Comment: @Lankymart I knew that there is no concept of MP in ASP. I'm sort of implement template(master page) in m project. FYKI I posted in the question what I tried and get some help from fellow developers to solve the issue. I'm definitely not looking for any "magic" function in this forumn, still it will be helpful if you give some solution/idea to the above question.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and include the CSS? Best way to debug rendering issues in the browser is check the page source HTML after the browser renders it using the browser dev tools. Remember Classic ASP is a server-side preprocessor which generates the HTML to send to the client which then renders it.

Comment: @Lankymart I have edited the question as you asked. Could you please check?

Comment: Not seeing any CSS, asked if you could [edit] the question to include the CSS not sure what you've added.

Comment: @Lankymart As you pointed out in your comment my issue with rendering(see the first image) thats why I given you exact page contents in the question. The CSS relative path in the mentioned in the "Header Page".

Comment: That doesn't look like the final rendered HTML though, it still contains ASP preprocessor tags `<% %>` for example.

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry for the delayed response. I have added the HTML Source to the question as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to open the CSS file through your browser, does it return as text or a blank page?

If a blank page, go to your Control Panel > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Common HTTP Features > Static Content. Set Static Content to on and then OK.

Reload the page now and see if the CSS renders.

Comment: it returns as text.